# Not able to inherit the One struct from another

Tags: solidity, remix

When I tried to inherit one struct from another struct, I am getting this error:

```
from solidity:
ParserError: Expected '{' but got 'is'
  --> contracts/Structure.sol:11:26:
   |
11 |     struct DerivedStruct is BaseStruct {
```

---

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Structure {
    struct BaseStruct {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
    }

    struct DerivedStruct is BaseStruct {
        uint256 c;
        uint256 d;
    }
}
```

Got this error:

[image]

Can't we inherit one struct to another in Solidity?

Answer (score 0):

You can inherit one sturct from another in Solidity.

Syntax you are using is incorrect. In solidity the 'is' keyword is used to inherit interfaces. To inherit form a struct you simply use its as the type of a new struct.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Structure {
    struct BaseStruct {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
    }

    struct DerivedStruct {
        BaseStruct base;
        uint256 c;
        uint256 d;
    }
}
```

`DerivedStruct` struct contains a `BaseStruct` field, which inherits its properties

Comment: That is not inheritance, but composition.